# New Facebook SDK Application Unavailable: The applicatioh you are trying to use is either no longer available or access is restricted

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

New users cannot log in via Facebook, receiving an error message saying: "Application not available: the application you are trying to use is no longer available or access is limited.".

Users have no problems accessing with their existing Facebook accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was on Facebook's current SDK. Please update the SDK this issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 19):

I get this issue when I create fake/test accounts on facebook. It seems like they take 1-2 hours to review the account before they will let you use the graphAPI.

Comment: I can second that the problem seems to be with brand new accounts, usually it works after a few hours

Comment: yep, this was the case with 2 of my newly created accounts

Answer (score 0):

If you just created a new business account, you will need to add one friend.